# SSIS foreach with a list of simple objects

Tags: sql-server, ssis, foreach

re: [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) [Foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141724.aspx) Loop task with a Variable:

I have this working for a List of primitive objects (e.g. a list of strings, as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674364/how-to-use-list-collection-for-foreach-in-ssis))

But how do you configure an SSIS ForEach task to loop through a `List<Dog>` or array `Dog[]` where `Dog` is a simple object like this:

```
public class Dog {
    public string Name{ get; set;}
    public string BestTrick{ get; set;}
}
```

Lets say I'm trying to get `Name` and `BestTrick` into two string loop variables for use inside the loop.

Mapping variables to position 0 and 1 on the 'variable mappings' tab doesn't seem to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The Foreach Loop in SSIS is used for iterating over a list of objects. So, for the example above you have a one dimensional list, `List<Dog>`, as an input to the loop. To get the current item in the list you need to specify a variable mapping to index 0.

If you had a two dimensional list, lets say `List<Dog,Owner>` then you would retrieve the current Dog object by mapping a variable to index 0, and the current Owner by mapping to index 1.

Once you have the current object in a variable you can get its properties by casting it to the appropriate type in a Script Task. Inside the script you can call `dog.Name` and save it to another variable for use in other components.

This is an example of the Script Task code (C#) which retrieves the dog object from a variable, and then saves its `Name` and `BestTrick` to two different variables.

```
 public void Main()

       Dog d = (Dog) Dts.Variables["Dog"].Value;

       Dts.Variables["DogName"].Value = d.Name;
       Dts.Variables["DogTrick"].Value = d.BestTrick;

    }
```

Please note that you will have to make each variable you want to edit or read known to the Script Task in its properties