# Adding month name to file in ssis

Tags: date, ssis

Is there any expression from which I can directly get the month name in expression builder?

I am supposed to add month name with file name dynamically. I am currently using "DATEPART" function from which i recieved the month number but I want Month name. Can anyone help me?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141671.aspx) there isn't one but some functions *are* missing for the list. You can use a script task to format a value and store the result to a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - unfortunately not. You have two options:

1. Return the month name from SQL as part of your dataset or
2. Do a bit of a crazy expression:

`(MONTH(yourDate) == 1 ? "January" : MONTH(yourDate) == 2 ? "February" :` `MONTH(yourDate) == 3 ? "March" : etc etc)`

Comment: Well! I have tried using the expression and it gives me the month name! :)

Answer (score 0):

SSIS Expressions have a very limited set of functions. If I remember correctly, it offers the functions that were available with VBScript way back when. There are no string formatting functions even in 2016 [according to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141671.aspx) and people end up concatenating the various parts of a string.

You can use a Script step though to format a date using String.Format and store the result in a variable,  as shown in [Using Variables in a Script Task] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135941.aspx) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192083/ssis-write-to-object-variable-through-script-task), eg:

```
var targetFolder=Dts.Variables["User::targetFolder"].Value;
var filePrefix=Dts.Variables["User::filePrefix"].Value;
var someDate=Dts.Variables["User::myDate"].Value;

var filePath= = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"{0}_{1:MMMM}.txt",filePrefix,someDate);
var fullPath=Path.Combine(targetFolder,filePath);

Dts.Variables["User::filePath"].Value=fullPath;
```

The advantage of a script task is that you can use all of .NET's functions to format values (eg String.Format) and manipulate paths (eg Path.Combine, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension etc)