# Converting DATETIME(Date Time) to Quarter(int) SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, script-component

I need to convert datetime to Quarter. I have date time as the date type - 2009-01-01 00:00:00.000

how do I convert this 01 to Quarter "1" for example?

Comment: I gave you a follow on to your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105494/converting-month-numberdate-time-or-4-byte-integer-to-month-namestring-ssis/63119679#63119679

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/datepart-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) you can use the `datepart` function with the `q` or `qq` argument:

```
datepart("q", YourDateColumn)
```