# Assign list to a ssis variable

Tags: c#, ssis

I tried to assign a list to a user variable , but it doesn't seems to work. Here is the code, what could be wrong?

```
StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Dts.Variables["User::filepath"].Value.ToString())
{
    string[] a = r.ReadLine().Split(';');
    List<string> list = new List<string>(a);             
    Dts.Variables["User::firstRow"].Value = list;
}
```

> at System.RuntimeMethod‌​Handle.InvokeMethod(O‌​bject target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) at
>   System.Reflection.Ru‌​ntimeMethodInfo.Unsaf‌​eInvokeInternal(Objec‌​t
>   obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) at
>   System.Reflection.Ru‌​ntimeMethodInfo.Invok‌​e(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>       at System.RuntimeType.I‌​nvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.‌​Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.‌​VSTATaskScriptingEngi‌​ne.ExecuteScript()

that is the error when I run the script in ssis

Comment: Define "doesn't seems to work".   Do you get an error?

Comment: at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

Comment: at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()  that is the error when I run the script in ssis

Comment: There must be more to the message.   The actual error is not anywhere in the part of the message you posted.

Comment: I know the message is not saying anything. But I dont get any more error message then it

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are trying to pass a List OBJECT into the user::firstrow variable.  Is that variable object type? Do you really want to pass the entire object?

I suspect though that because your variable says "firstrow" that you actually only want the first string from the list in which case just specify the proper index.

So change:

```
 Dts.Variables["User::firstRow"].Value = list;
```

To

```
 Dts.Variables["User::firstRow"].Value = list[0];
```

Edit per your comment

based on this answer [how to use list collection for "foreach" in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674364/how-to-use-list-collection-for-foreach-in-ssis) it looks like it is possible to use a list object. I have never actually tried it, but I have passed around recordsets.  But if the variable is an object then it should work to store the list according to that link.  There are a few other potential issues then. 1 your User::firstrow is not listed as a ReadWriteVariable available for the script, your User::filepath is not listed as a ReadOnlyVariable... You are not testing whether there is a line to read.... Tab is right there is more to the error and I know debugging is difficult for ssis scripts.  But you can use System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show() to show the exception.  Just wrap everything in a Try Catch Block and in the catch do MessageBox.Show(exception.TosTring()).  So something like this:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    throw;
}
```

All of this begs the question of what you are attempting to do though because taking a list out of a script task for 1 row then pass to what a foreach loop to set variable?  It would be easiest just to set the variables directly in c# script......

Comment: The varaible is an object type. And list is a list , I want to pass the entire list into the variable instaed of one. Is it possible?

Comment: I updated answer with some additional questions/comments